# Choosing PrecisionGoal and AccuracyGoal for decomposed integral with NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, precision-and-accuracy

Assume I have a complicated integral $I$ which can feature all kinds of difficulties like infinite interval, rapidly oscillatory integrand, integrable singularities and numerically almost singular points in the integrand. Assume further that I need to compute it many times, so I need to optimize speed. I figured that I need to help Mathematica  a bit to avoid problems such as `NIntegrate::slwcon` if I do not want to increase `MaxIterations`, `MinIterations`, `WorkingPrecision` a lot, which would decrease speed. So I decompose the domain of integration into several $I=I_1+I_2+I_3\ldots I_n$ ($n$ finite). `NIntegrate` behaves better now and I can manually perform integral transformations and choose well suited Methods for the different domains. However: With fixed `AccuracyGoal` and `PressicionGoal` for each of $I_i$ `NIntegrate` will choose sufficiently many sampling points and iterations to achieve these error levels, even if the total contribution of $I_i$ is negligibly small. How would you proceed (how would you choose `AccuracyGoal` and `PressicionGoal` for the individual integrands) to reduce the total number of integrand evalutations to the minimum required as to achieve given global values of `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`? Since the integrand of $I$ is fixed I can reorder $I_i$ such that difficult but possibly small ones appear late and I can use the previous results as estimates for the total value of $I$. However assume that I do not have any analytic estimates for $I_i$.

Comment: It seems that you should set `PrecisionGoal` to `Infinity` ([i.e. to switch off this option](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/192571?p_p_auth=imSWdJ5b)) and set equal `AccuracyGoal` for all integrals. Note that `PrecisionGoal` is meant to specify the *relative* error of the result while `AccuracyGoal` - *absolute* error.

Comment: But this solution would imply that I can't specify a relative error, unless I know an approximate result, for the total Integral.

Comment: I had not investigated how `AccuracyGoal` actually affects selection of evaluation points for the integrand on each stage of `NIntegrate`'s recursive algorithm. Assuming that increasing `AccuracyGoal` just adds new levels of recursion and does not alter previous you could use memoization and compute the complete integral in two stages: at first stage you compute it with little value of `AccuracyGoal` (which you still should guess), at the second stage you set `AccuracyGoal` you actually wish based on the estimate from the 1'st stage.

Comment: Of course it is not a general solution, just a partial workaround for the case when evaluation of the integrand(s) is very time-consuming.

Comment: How would 'memoization' work? Probably it would depend then on the integration routine too as not all algorithms can make use of previous evaluation points as far as I understand.

Comment: See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25150/280) as a reference for *memoization*. Yes, it depends on the integration routine whether memoization is suitable or not.